# Checkboxes array of bools doesnt brings the true value if it's checked by user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-5, view

I have a list of Checkboxes in a bool array, I wish I could give the Checked value as a "true" in that specific checkbox if it's checked by user

This is my model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace testnumbers.Models
{
    public class StringNumber
    {
        [Required]
        public bool[] array = new bool[27];
        public double Numerito { get; set; }
        public double numero(bool[] array){
            int i = 0;
            double result=0.0;
            double temp=0.0;
            foreach (bool str in array){
                if( str == true)
                    temp=1.0;
                else
                    temp=0.0;
                result+= temp* System.Math.Pow(2,(double)i);
                i++;
            }
        return result;
        }
    }
}
```

My controller 2 actions:
         using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;
        using System.Web.Mvc;
        using testnumbers.Models;

```
    namespace testnumbers.Controllers
    {
        public class StringNumberController : Controller
        {
            // GET: StringNumber
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                //StringNumber number = new StringNumber();
                return View(new StringNumber());
            }
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Result(StringNumber number)
            {
                 //model not valid, do not save, but return current umbraco page
                if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
                {
                    RedirectToAction("index");
                }

                number.Numerito = number.numero(number.array);
                return View(number);
            }
        }
    }
```

and the view:
        @model testnumbers.Models.StringNumber
        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        }
        
            Inspired in: [This post for Customs GPOs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/231289)

```
       @using (Html.BeginForm("Result", "StringNumber", FormMethod.Post )) {  //,new { StringNumber = Model }
           @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
           string[] str = { "Z", "Y", "X", "W", "V", "U", "T", "S", "R", "Q", "P", "O", "N", "M", "L", "K", "J", "I", "H", "G", "F", "E", "D", "C", "B", "A" }; int i = 0; <table>
            <tr>
                @for (i = 0; i < Model.array.Count() - 1; i++)
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.array[i])

                    <td>@str[i] : @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.array[i])</td>
                }
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit"  />
    }
```

The view alwys got thr values of the bool array as false and I would like to update to "true" those checkboxes that were selected to the controller and can do the work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make your `array` field a property

Comment: Isn't that done?
       public bool[] array = new bool[27];
       public double numero(bool[] array){

Comment: As far as I can see, no.

Comment: You are right, now I know what you where saying, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the hidden input your creating for the same property

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.array[i])
```

The `DefaultModelBinder` reads the first name/value pair match your property name and binds it. Any subsequent name/value pairs are ignored so the value of the inputs created by

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.array[i])
```

are ignored. You also need to give your field getters and setters so the `DefaultModelBinder` can set the values on post back (i.e make it a property).

```
public bool[] array { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer following the Stephen  and haim770 Solutions. Thank you

```
  public class StringNumber
{
    [Required]

    public bool[] array { get; set; }
    public double Numerito { get; set; }
    public double numero(bool[] array){
        int i = 0;
        double result=0.0;
        double temp=0.0;
        foreach (bool str in array){
            if( str == true)
                temp=1.0;
            else
                temp=0.0;
            result+= temp* System.Math.Pow(2,(double)i);
            i++;
        }
    return result;
    }
}
```